# How to dynamically get values from JSON Android/Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know there are tons of json question here, but i was searching for literally HOURS and no result for me,

i want to ask how to get the VALUES from JSONObject (or jsonString i dont know, i can manage both) but dynamically...

```
{
   "clientes":[
      {
         "codigo":"1341",
         "empresa":0,
         "nombre":"asd asd",
         "e_mail":"cliente@test.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

I could already get the keys dynamically from a nested json (the one above) to put them later in the sqlite statement, I am putting together an INSERT OR REPLACE statement. Where the columns: I put the array that I get from the keys with a `for`.

but I have searched for hours how to do the same but with the values I think it will be done with a `for` as well, but could someone help me or tell me how I should do it? My goal is to build a contentValues or a string array with the values of each key, and then put them in the VALUES statement sentence

Comment: If u get the keys u can just use the key to get the values using same for loop

Comment: JSONObject object = new JSONObject ();
JSONArray keys = object.names ();

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length (); i++) {
   
   String key = keys.getString (i); // Here's your key
   String value = object.getString (key); // Here's your value
   
} some thing like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), which is a library that automatically converts a Java object to a Json string and vice versa.
This is the simplest example I could give:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Client c = new Client(); /* this is your object */
String json = gson.toJson(c);
Client converted = gson.fromJson(json, Client.class);
```